# Error: Undefined is not a function - React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I created a simple activity where in if you press inside the circular area, the text in it should change accordingly. The app runs well but when I press inside the circular area, I get an error saying "undefined is not a function ( evaluating 'this.setState( {pressing: true});' )     ". 
Also, the text inside the circular area should be initially set but it is empty. 
You can see the activity [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M8OA.png). The code is also provided below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight
} from "react-native";

class dhrumil extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { pressing: false };
  }
  _inPress() {
    this.setState({ pressing: true });
  }
  _outPress() {
    this.setState({ pressing: false });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPressIn={this._inPress}
          onPressOut={this._outPress}
          style={styles.toucher}
        >
          <View style={styles.smallContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.texter}>
              {this.state.pressing ? "EEK" : "PUSH ME"}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    justifyContent: "center",
    margin: 10,
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  toucher: {
    borderRadius: 100
  },
  smallContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 100
  },
  texter: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent("dhrumil", () => dhrumil);
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPressIn={this._inPress}
onPressOut={this._outPress}  style={styles.toucher}>
```

You are setting handlers without fixing the context as the current `this`.
So when the functions are called `setState` is not found as `this` will be different. Use `bind`.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPressIn={this._inPress.bind(this)}
   onPressOut={this._outPress.bind(this)}  style={styles.toucher}>
```

Or you can also use arrow function:

```
 <TouchableHighlight onPressIn={() => this._inPress()}
       onPressOut={() => this._outPress()}  style={styles.toucher}>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply delete node_modules

run npm install

react-native run-android

It's worked for me.