# Behavior of `this` in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am just getting started with react native and have some problems understanding what `this` in what context refers to.

I saw this simple example in some tutorial:

```
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onPress={this.buttonAction}></Button>
      </View>)}
  buttonAction() {
    this.setState(...);
  }
}
```

Now I wanted to build my own button component, so I write this `MButton.js`

```
class MButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress}>
        <View>
          <Text>Login</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );}}
```

And tried to use it in my main container:

```
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MButton onPress={this.buttonAction}></MButton>
      </View>)}
  buttonAction() {
    this.setState(...);
  }
}
```

But now `this` inside of `buttonAction()` refers to the `MButton` objects and `setState` is not callable.

Coming from a web/js background this somehow makes sense, but why did it work in the first place then? How would one go about doing this? Can I access the parent component somehow? Or should I do something completely different?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44434301/4826457

Comment: React native does not change how javascript works. I have modified the tags.

Comment: @Sulthan actually he shared the code snippet from react-native.So,it needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **now `this` inside of buttonAction() refers to the MButton objects?**

NO.Its not referring the `MButton` object.

> **setState is not callable ?**

You need to bind `this` to `buttonAction`

**Sol1 :**

Use **[`arrow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** function.

```
buttonAction=() =>{
    this.setState(...);
}
```

**Sol2 :**

in constructor :

```
constructor(){

  this.buttonAction = this.buttonAction.bind(this);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <MButton onPress={() => {this.buttonAction()}}>
                </MButton>
            </View>
        )
    }

    buttonAction() {
        this.setState(...);
    }
}
```

onPress={() => {this.buttonAction()}}
with the help of arrow function we can pass parameters to MButton component (if u whant to pass).

Comment: So is there a best practice? Should I rather bind `this` or use this inline function solution?

Comment: @DavidNathan   I think the inline function solution is best practice because if you want to pass any parameters in future you can pass on.